# Keep missing data in ggplot2 stacked barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]This is my sample data. ID 144 contains 6 positions while ID AB01 contains only 3. In a stacked plot I still want to show 6 positions in AB01 with missing positions shown in a specific color .

```
ID   YEAR  POS
    144 2017   10
    144 2017  12
    144 2017  18
    144 2017  15
    144 2017  163
    144 2017 200
    AB01 2018  10
    AB01 2018 15
    AB01 2018 18
```

This is what I tried.

```
ggplot(data1, aes(x = ID, y=1, fill = as.factor(POS))) +
 geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", exclude = NULL) +
 facet_wrap(~ data1$Year, ncol=1, scale="free") +
 labs(x="Year", y= "Number ", fill = "Position", Title= "Pos plot") +
 theme(text = element_text(size = 15, color = "Black"))
```

data

```
data <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("144", "AB01"), class = "factor"), YEAR = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), POS = c(10L, 12L, 18L, 15L, 163L, 200L, 10L, 15L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: You could add extra artificial entries to the dataframe with AB01 in the ID column to make it up to 6.

Comment: Can you copy/paste your data into Stack using the `dput` function? That way I can try it out on my computer

Comment: Could you include a sketch of what your expected graph should look like?

Comment: Friendly reminder that `geom_col(...)` is shorthand for  `geom_bar(stat = "identity", ...)`.

Comment: @Peter : added a sketch

Comment: @DanielFreeman structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("144", "AB01"), class = "factor"), YEAR = c(2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), POS = c(10L, 
12L, 18L, 15L, 163L, 200L, 10L, 15L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `geom_tile` instead?

```
data <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("144", "AB01"), class = "factor"), YEAR = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), POS = c(10L, 12L, 18L, 15L, 163L, 200L, 10L, 15L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

ggplot(data, aes(x = ID, y = as.factor(POS), fill = as.factor(POS))) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  coord_cartesian(expand = F) + # get rid of space around tiles
  theme_classic() # make background white
```

Comment: I can but I also need to show year of the data so I can use a facet_wrap but that will show positions for that year or order my data according to year and draw a vertical line demarking 2017 2018 boundry.

Comment: It looks like year and ID vary together. Can you just paste those columns together? `facet_wrap` will leave weird gaps

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = ID, y = as.factor(POS), fill = as.factor(POS))) +
geom_tile(color = "black") + facet_wrap(~ data1$Year, ncol=2, scale="free_x") + 
coord_cartesian(expand = F) + theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text.x = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```r
data <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("144", "AB01"), class = "factor"), YEAR = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), POS = c(10L, 12L, 18L, 15L, 163L, 200L, 10L, 15L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))



library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)


data_1 <- 
  data %>% 
  mutate(temp = as.character(POS)) %>%
  complete(ID, POS) %>% 
  mutate(temp = fct_explicit_na(fct_inseq(temp), na_level = "Missing"))


col_map <- c("10" = "powderblue",
             "12" = "red",
             "18" = "orange",
             "15" = "yellow",
             "163" = "green",
             "200" = "blue",
             "Missing" = "White")

ggplot(data_1, aes(x = ID, y = fct_rev(factor(POS)), fill = temp)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black", width = 0.5, height = 0.8) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col_map)+
  coord_cartesian(expand = F) + 
  labs(x = NULL, 
       y = NULL,
       fill = NULL)+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.line = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Updated to include spaces between rectangles as in sample data.